# Not able run Spring boot application as runnable jar from command prompt

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, spring-boot

I'm able to run application from my eclipse, but when i create jar try to run from command prompt it giving error. i'm using java 1.8 and eclipse kepler

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext app = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    Application application = app.getBean(Application.class);
    if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
        application.getAllApiByProject(args);
    } else {
        System.out.print("No Arguments found.., Pass Project argument");
    }
    final int exitCode = 0;
    ExitCodeGenerator exitCodeGenerator = new ExitCodeGenerator() {

        @Override
        public int getExitCode() {
            return exitCode;
        }
    };
    SpringApplication.exit(app, exitCodeGenerator);
    System.out.print("Closing App Spring boot");
 }

public void getAllApiByProject(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Opening App Spring boot");
     if (args != null && args.length == 1) {
        apiService.getAllApiByProject(args[0]);
     } else {
        String apiId = args[1];
        apiService.getApiById(Integer.parseInt(apiId));
     }
   }

   @Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context;

   @Autowired
   private ApiService apiService;

}
```

i'm creating jar from using below commands

```
mvn package
mvn spring-boot:run
```

i'm getting below error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1125) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2017-02-10 21:00:24.422 ERROR 4844 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
```

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) [spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at com.relevancelab.imdg.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:507) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
        ... 6 common frames omitted

```
2017-02-10 21:00:24.422  WARN 4844 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2017-02-10 21:00:24.423  INFO 4844 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-02-10 21:00:24.431 ERROR 4844 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at com.relevancelab.imdg.Application.main(Application.java:17) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:507) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:115) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:82) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:535) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:177) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 25 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:507)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175)
    at com.relevancelab.imdg.Application.main(Application.java:17)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

at
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:96)
        ... 19 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 21 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 25 more
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-      plugin
    :1.4.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project IMDG: An exception occurred while running. null: 
    InvocationTargetException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: 
    Unable to start embedded Tomcat: 
    Failed to start component [Standar
    dServer[-1]]: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]: 
    A child container failed during start ->
Dependency Tree

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ IMDG ---
[INFO] relevancelab:IMDG:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.4.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.10.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.12.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.4.1212.jre7:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:jar:2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.8.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:1.8.0.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5-cdh5.8.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- jline:jline:jar:2.11:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.jboss.netty:netty:jar:3.2.2.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-common:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:apache-log4j-extras:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-service:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.jpam:jpam:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.thrift:libfb303:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-serde:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.twitter:parquet-hadoop-bundle:jar:1.5.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.jolbox:bonecp:jar:0.8.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.12.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jdo:jar:3.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.datanucleus:datanucleus-rdbms:jar:3.2.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hive:hive-shims:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-common:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-0.23:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy:jar:2.6.0-cdh5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hive.shims:hive-shims-scheduler:jar:1.1.0-cdh5.4.0:runtime
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:jar:0.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.22:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.8:system
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.htrace:htrace-core:jar:3.1.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.23.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xerces:xercesImpl:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tomcat failed to start. The reason why will be in the log output. Can you share all of the output from starting your app?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, Update the complete error

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, i have added dependency tree, can u plz help in resolving conflict, i tried but not able to solve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause of the failure is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1125) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

This tells me that you have an old version (probably 2.5) of the Servlet API on the classpath. You're using Tomcat 8.5.6 which is a Servlet 3.1-compatible server. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to identify where the old Servlet API is being pulled in and then add an `<exclusion>` to your pom to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The maven *package* doesn't include external dependencies, so, you can package jars only to serve as a library to another project. Use the spring boot maven plugin and *repackage* instead, to package runnable spring boot jars, as bellow:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
java -jar target/spring-boot-project.jar
```

Read this arcticle for further information: 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-run-maven-vs-executable-jar